# ColdFusion 10 automatic updates are not getting applied

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We are installing CF10 Enterprise on Windows 2008 RC2 with IIS 7.

We installed using all default selections, straight-forward installation, and applied the mandatory update.  So far, so good. When we go to the updates page for automatic updates for the latest current hotfix (7 at the time of this post), which is cumulative, the install and download process runs fine, the instance restarts, but then when we check again to see the available updates, it shows all the updates from 1 to 7 again, as if we didn't apply the updates at all.  Installed updates tab shows no updates having been applied. 
However, looking at the system info page, the udpate level shows HF7.

We tried a variation, applying one hotfix at a time.  This worked through hotfix 2, but after applying hotfix 4, it 'froze' there with the same problem as described above, not showing any fixes having been applied after hotfix 2.
This is incredibly frustrating.  I have no idea if hotfixes have been applied, and am not sure what to think about the system info page indicating hotfix level. We are still living in ColdFusion update hell.

Comment: I don't think you are the only one - [ColdFusion 10 version number inconsistency](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4994336)

Comment: For what it's worth I also found 2 bugs entered that might be related to this; [1 - Administrator Info Page Displays Incorrect Version Number](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3325078) and [2 - cfinfo reports wrong version number](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3427668). I recall seeing some other posts on the Adobe forums as well. Suffice to say I think CF10 has issues with reporting the correct version number.

Comment: If this file exists: cfusion/lib/updates/chf10000007.jar then the hotfix should be installed. You can also checkout the cfusion/hf-updates/ folder and it should have install logs for each one that was installed. The install logs should list any errors, and will also say which files were updated.

Comment: Thank you. Zeroing in more on the problem, I am seeing an error message in the log file that is created by the hotfix process, typically found in ColdFusion10\cfusion\hf-updates\..*.log
The error is "Failed to copy the hotfix files to the target location".
This looks like a permission problem. The only information I can find is that the account running CF needs to have read/write permission on the directory. The CF service logs on as "Local System Account", which should have permissions so I'm not sure if that error is correct

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help.  We have solved the issue, I will post the solution here if it helps anyone in the future. The error message logged in the hotfix log file  (Eg: C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\hf-updates\hf-10-00007) is the following:

Failed to copy hotfix files:C:\Users\xxx\002873.tmp\dist\cfusion
Status: FATAL ERROR
Additional Notes: FATAL ERROR - Failed to copy the hotfix files to the target location:C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion
FATAL ERROR - C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\coldfusion.exe (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Several blog posts refer to permission problems, such as making sure the account under which CF10 runs has local admin access, or that the cfusion directory have appropriate permissions.  We had tried these solutions, and several variations without luck. We had also stopped all CF services and applied the HF manually but the same error persisted.

In our case, we renamed coldfusion.exe notated in the error log above, applied the hotfix, and everything worked. So, I don't believe it was really a permissions issue but rather (as the error log was trying to tell us), that the coldfusion.exe was in use.

*Note: For Update 11 issued 7/9/13, renaming coldfusionsvc.exe (in our case, to coldfusionsvc_1.exe) was required in addition to renaming coldfusion.exe*